# React Bootstrap Dropdown Menu not functioning correctly

Tags: node.js, reactjs, drop-down-menu, header, navbar

I'm having an issue with a basic dropdown menu and I can't figure out why it's not functioning.

Here's the code

```
<pre><code>

import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav';
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
import NavDropdown from 'react-bootstrap/NavDropdown';

function DropdownMenu() {

  return (
    <Navbar variant="dark" bg="dark" expand="lg">
      <Container fluid>
      <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="dropdown-menu" />
      <Navbar.Collapse id="dropdown-menu">
      <Nav>
            <NavDropdown title= "Menu" id="dropdown-menu"
            activeClassName="bg-black hover:bg-gray-900 text-gray-400 transition"
              className="bg-black hover:bg-gray-900 text-gray-400 text-lg py-3 px-6 lg:py-4 lg:px-8 cursor-pointer rounded-t-md font-medium transition items-center">
                              <NavDropdown.Divider />
                            
              <NavDropdown.Item href="/"                                                         className="bg-black hover:bg-gray-900 text-gray-400 text-lg cursor-pointer rounded-t-md font-medium transition items-center">                                                           <div>Home</div>
              </NavDropdown.Item>
            </NavDropdown>
          </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Container>
    </Navbar>
  );
}

export default DropdownMenu;

</pre></code>
```

I've attached a photo of what it's doing. It's dropping down the link, but expanding the navbar as it drops down, it's not becoming an actual dropdown menu, it's just adding more lines into the navbar.

I also call it within the header on the page, here's the code for the header:

```
<pre><code>

import React, { Component, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { observer, inject } from 'mobx-react'
import { computed,  } from 'mobx'
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'
import { SwitchHorizontalIcon, ScaleIcon, DatabaseIcon, UserCircleIcon,
} from '@heroicons/react/outline'
import { IconDashboard, IconDatabase } from './Icons'
import { useLocation, } from 'react-router-dom'
import Body from './Components/Body'
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import DropdownMenu from './Components/DropwdownMenu';

function HeaderExpand(props) {
//notes: the HeaderExpand component is a functional component that returns a React element
//notes: props is an object that contains the properties of the component

    const location = useLocation();

    return <SuperHeader 
            >{props.children}
    </SuperHeader>
}

@inject('store')
//notes: the inject decorator is used to inject the store into the component
@observer
//notes: the observer decorator is used to make the component reactive
class SidebarCompontent extends Component {
//notes: the SidebarCompontent component is a class component that extends the Component class
//notes: this is useful because it allows us to use the Component class to create a component

    constructor(props) {

        super(props);

        if(this.props.location.pathname === "/signup"){
            this.props.history.push('/')
        }

        if(this.props.location.pathname === "/login"){
            this.props.history.push('/')
        }
        
    }


    @computed get fromColor(){
        if(this.props.store.profile.credits <= 0){
        //notes: this is a conditional statement that checks if the value of the credits property of the profile property of the store is less than or equal to 0
            return "bg-red-200 text-red-600"
        }
        if(this.props.store.profile.status === "trialing"){
            return ""
        }
        if(this.props.store.profile.status === "active"){
            return ""
        }
        if(this.props.store.profile.status === "incomplete"){
            return ""
        }
        return "bg-red-200 text-red-600"
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                            <Textarea readOnly name="copy-textarea" id="copy-textarea" value={this.props.store.copyToClipboardText}  />
                                <div className="border-b border-gray-300 bg-black shadow-sm ">
                                        <div className="container flex select-none">
                                            
                                                        < DropdownMenu>
                                            
                                                        </DropdownMenu>
                                                </div>
                                                
                                </div>
                                {this.props.children}
                        </>
            )
        }

}   





const Input = styled.input` `
const Textarea = styled.textarea`
    position: fixed;
    right:-9990px;
    top:-9990px;
`

// transition:ease-in-out 0.5s margin-top;
//  transition-delay:0.05s;

const SuperHeader = styled.div`
    height:150px;
    background:black;
    display:${props => props.hidden ? "hidden" : "flex" };
    background-image:url(${require('./Logo.svg').default}); 
    background-size:auto 50%;
    background-position: 20px 20px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    position:relative;  
`



    
export default withRouter(SidebarCompontent)


</pre></code>
```

Any help would be amazing!

I'm trying to get it to drop down like an actual navbar and nothing seems to be working.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-navbar-usbxgm?file=/src/index.js Does this help?

Comment: If you open with this: 
`<pre><code>`  


You cant close like this 

`</pre></code>` 

Swap the tags around as shown below:

`</code></pre>`

Your final should look as follows

```html
<pre><code>
// ... your exsisting code
</code></pre>
```